# how to read a file present on the edge node when submit spark application in deploy mode = cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I have an spark scala application( spark 2.4 ). I am passing a file present on my *edge node* as an argument to my driver(main) program, I read this file using `scala.io.Source` .Now when i do a spark-submit and mention `--deploy-mode client`then the application runs fine and it can read the file. But when i use `deploy-mode cluster`.   the application fails saying file not found. Is there a way i can read the file from the edge node in cluster mode.

Thanks.

Edit..

I tried giving file:// before the file path but hat is not working either...
this is how i am giving the file path as an argument to my main class.

```
spark2-submit --jars spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4G  --executor-memory 4G  --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 6  --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 --conf spark.executor.instances=150 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true  --class com.citi.gct.main.StartGCTEtl  global-consumer-etl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  file://home/gfrrtnee/aditya/Trigger_1250-ING-WS-ALL-PCL-INGEST-CPB_20200331_ING-GLOBAL-PCL-CPB-04-Apr-19-1.event dev Y
```

But still i am getting the same error in cluster mode.

```
20/05/07 06:27:47 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/gfrrtnee/aditya/Trigger_1250-ING-WS-ALL-PCL-INGEST-CPB_20200331_ING-GLOBAL-PCL-CPB-04-Apr-19-1.event (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Answer (score 2):

In `cluster` mode, you can use the `--files` option of `spark-submit`.

Example: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark?topic=AnalyticsforApacheSpark-specify-file-path

Another option for you is to place the file in a distributed file system like `hdfs` or `dbfs`.

Comment: Hi Aravind, Thanks for the answer , but this is not working..I don't want to place the file on the hdfs and read it. i want to keep this file on the edge node and want to access in deploy-mode cluser.

Comment: In the spark-submit command, I don't see you using the "--files" option before file://....